# Reading Very Large One Liner Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers, text-files, large-files

I have a 30MB .txt file, with ***one*** line of data *(30 Million Digit Number)*
Unfortunately, every method I've tried (`mmap.read()`, `readline()`, allocating 1GB of RAM, for loops) takes 45+ minutes to completely read the file.
Every method I found on the internet seems to work on the fact that each line is small, therefore the memory consumption is only as big as the biggest line in the file. Here's the code I've been using.

```
start = time.clock()
z = open('Number.txt','r+') 
m = mmap.mmap(z.fileno(), 0)
global a
a = int(m.read())
z.close()
end = time.clock()
secs = (end - start)
print("Number read in","%s" % (secs),"seconds.", file=f)
print("Number read in","%s" % (secs),"seconds.")
f.flush()
del end,start,secs,z,m
```

Other than splitting the number from one line to various lines; which I'd rather not do, is there a cleaner method which won't require the better part of an hour?

By the way, I don't necessarily have to use text files.

I have: Windows 8.1 64-Bit, 16GB RAM, Python 3.5.1

Comment: Reading a 30MB file is quick.  It's the `int(filecontent)` that is slow.

Comment: Are you aware that converting it will cause an approximation on it, more or less depending on the type you choose? You won't keep all the gazillion digits of it.

Comment: ...I mean, of course you might be able to work on that number, but the standard types won't hold 30 million significant digits all in one number. They'll approximate. You'll have to either search for, or implement, a way to do it.

Comment: @Roberto Thanks for the advice, but it looks like gmpy2 hasn't rounded anything, I had it print the results directly to a second file and compare the numbers, which found that they were exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the gmpy2 module to convert the string to a number.

```
start = time.clock()  
z=open('Number.txt','r+') 
data=z.read()
global a
a=gmpy2.mpz(data)
end = time.clock()
secs = (end - start)
print("Number read in","%s" % (secs),"seconds.", file=f)
print("Number read in","%s" % (secs),"seconds.")
f.flush()
del end,secs,start,z,data
```

It worked in 3 seconds, much slower, but at least it gave me an integer value.

Thank you all for your invaluable answers, however I'm going to mark this one as soon as possible.

Answer (score 11):

The file read is quick (<1s):

```
with open('number.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Converting a 30-million-digit string to an integer, that's slow:

```
z=int(data) # still waiting...
```

If you store the number as raw big- or little-endian binary data, then `int.from_bytes(data,'big')` is much quicker.

If I did my math right (Note `_` means "last line's answer" in Python's interactive interpreter):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log(10)/math.log(2)  # Number of bits to represent a base 10 digit.
3.3219280948873626
>>> 30000000*_                # Number of bits to represent 30M-digit #.
99657842.84662087
>>> _/8                       # Number of bytes to represent 30M-digit #.
12457230.35582761             # Only ~12MB so file will be smaller :^)
>>> import os
>>> data=os.urandom(12457231) # Generate some random bytes
>>> z=int.from_bytes(data,'big')  # Convert to integer (<1s)
99657848
>>> math.log10(z)   # number of base-10 digits in number.
30000001.50818886
```

**EDIT**: FYI, my math wasn't right, but I fixed it.  Thanks for 10 upvotes without noticing :^)

Comment: If I try to use the int.from_bytes(data,'big'), then I get a "TypeError: cannot convert unicode object to bytes"

Comment: @Master-chip Read it with 'rb' to get binary data.

Comment: Oops, that was embarrassing.  It works great, it read it in 0.39 seconds, thank you.

Comment: This is giving some different numbers to what I input. If I try it on a small byte number, say "b'1234'", then I get 825373492 for big, and 875770417 for little. If I decode the it, I get the value I'm looking for, but as a string, which brings me back to square one.

Comment: @Master-chip You stated you don't have to use a text file. I'm suggesting saving the number as a raw binary big- or little-endian number. `b'\x12\x34'` (two bytes) instead of `b'1234'` (four bytes). It's the data conversion from text to internal binary format that is expensive.

Comment: That would mean that I have to save the number inside my script, which would cause a massive slow down in editing. What I meant was that I could use a different extension if that would help, sorry for the confusion. Could I still apply this to work with a text file or another sort of file though?

Comment: @Master-chip Oops, actual decimal b'1234' would store as hex bytes b'\x04\xd2' (big-endian), but I hope you understand what `from_bytes` does.  I guess the question is how did you get this 30M-digit text file and can its generation be changed to write it out in binary instead?  But it sounds like `gmpy2` has solved your problem.  I'm surprised `gmpy2` is so much faster than the built-in `int()` in Python.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "save the number inside my script" as well.  I'm saying change how the data is *originally* stored in the file to make reading it in faster, if possible.

Comment: That makes more sense now that you mention it. Thanks for everything. By the way, gmpy2 _does_ do some magic every time I use it, it's rather impressive.

Answer (score 3):

A 30MB text file should not take very long to read, modern hard drives should be able to do this in less than a second (not counting access time)

Using the standard python file IO should work fine in this case:

```
with open('my_file', 'r') as handle:
    content = handle.read()
```

Using this on my laptop yields times much less than a second.

However, converting those 30 MB to an integer is your bottleneck, 
since python cannot represent this with the `long` datatype.

You can have a try with the Decimal module, however it is mainly designed for floating point arithmetic.

Besides of that, there is numpy of course, which might be faster (and since you probably want to do some work with the number later on, it would make sense to use such a library).

Comment: Wouldn't Numpy have the same problem though? They are both trying to convert a very big string to a number.